# how to implement jQuery - prettyCheckable? onClick event not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to implement jQuery prettyCheckable and really i got a nice style :D, but onclick event stopped working for me. I need onclick event in my input checkbox for to call the function.

this checkbox works succesful:

```
<input id="checkId" type="checkbox" onClick="myFunction()"  />

function myFunction() {alert('works! :D');}
```

this checkbox is very beautiful, but no work onClick event:

```
$('input.checkStyle').prettyCheckable();

<input id="checkId" type="checkbox" class="checkStyle" onClick="myFunction()"  />

function myFunction() {alert('not work :(');}
```

more information about prettyCheckable here: http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/

Thx and sorry my english!

Comment: I'm not sure if your code really looks like that, you didn't have <script> tag around your function, and your function appears AFTER the onClick listener which cannot be trigger.

Comment: Don't use embedded javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not firing because you aren't clicking on it. You are clicking on placeholder spans that are style-able. To detect the checkbox input changing, use the jquery change event instead of listening for a click.

```
$('input.checkStyle').prettyCheckable();

$('#checkId').on('change', myFunction);

function myFunction() {alert('not work :(');}
```

Comment: I'm trying -> $('#checkId').on('change', myFunction()); function myFunction() {alert('hello world');}  but not work for me.

Comment: not ` $('#checkId').on('change', myFunction());` its ` $('#checkId').on('change', myFunction);`

Comment: I am testing this code: $('#checkId').on('change', alert('hello world')); this is correct?   how could I make the call to this function? function checkAll(parameter1, parameter2) ->  $('#checkId').on('change', checkAll(parameter1, parameter2);? i dont understand it very well, sorry.

Comment: ok $('#checkId').on('click', function() {
      alert('hello world');
     }); this work for me :)

Comment: you are not understand the basic syntax, you cannot put calling () inside and existing set without the function keyword.

Comment: just to bring notice closing bracket is missing  for alert displayed inside the myFunction()

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathan Chow said, you may have forgotten to place your Javascript / Jquery code between tags as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        alert('WORKS');
    }
</script>
<input id="checkId" type="checkbox" class="checkStyle" onClick="myFunction()"  />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

However, it should be noted that:

You don't necessarily need the "**onClick**" attribute as you are using jQuery, which is geared towards ease in manipulation and access of the DOM.

As such, the solution can be rewritten as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#checkId').click(function() {
         alert('WORKS');
    });
</script>
<input id="checkId" type="checkbox" class="checkStyle"  />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

At this point, all you have to do is use the jQuery **prettyCheckable** function (provided that it is loaded), and you're all set. An example of this would then be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#checkId').click(function() {
         $(this).prettyCheckable();
    });
</script>
<input id="checkId" type="checkbox" class="checkStyle"  />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: I have javascript tags in my real code. I thought it was understood for this example. I also tried your code, but neither worked. : (

Comment: @jrd1 if you use $(this).prettyCheckable(); on each click or change function. it will just duplicate the input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about what do you need to accomplish here. If you want to detect when your checkbox or radio was checked (which happens when you click it) you should add the on change event to it.

First, create your input on your HTML and import prettyCheckable CSS and JS files.

```
<input id="checkId" type="checkbox" class="checkStyle"  />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Then, on an appropriate javascript markup, initialise the plugin, define your function, then add the .on('change') event to it, using a proper selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#checkId').prettyCheckable();

  function myFunction() {alert('Works!')}; 

  $('#checkId').on('change', myFunction);

</script>
```

This should do the trick.